# where to find source codes of mutex, future, etc in Linux?

Tags: c++, glibc

Container codes can be found in `/usr/include/c++/4.8.5/bits`. What about source codes of other stl libs, such as mutex, future, etc?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Thread related stuff under unix is based on libpthread.

Comment: ... in `bits` too. Hardcore way to find out a few: `$ grep -ri "class future :" /usr/include/c++` gives `/usr/include/c++/8.2.1/future:    class future : public __basic_future<_Res>` for me.

Comment: You can down load the entire source code for the compiler and the libraries from the GCC website. https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/

Comment: You may be able to check it out as a package in whatever package manager is used by whatever Linux distribution you are using, but the GCC source code does not normally come pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

glibc uses NPTL on Linux, and the mutex implementation is split across various directories:

- `nptl`: High-level POSIX threads mutexes in the `pthread_mutex_*.c` source files.
- `sysdeps/nptl`: Documentation and stubs for the futex wrappers in `lowlevellock*.h`.
- `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux`: `futex` system call wrappers in `lowlevellock-futex.h`.
- Architecture-specific subdirectories such as `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64`: Inline assembler functions for low-level lock operations in `lowlevellock.h` and `lowlevellock.S`.

Most synchronization types in `libstdc++` (the C++ standard library implementation in GCC) are themselves wrappers around the `libpthread` library component of glibc (only on GNU/Linux, of course).